# How to add the QuickTest.dll on c# for automating UFT

Tags: c#, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I am trying to integrate c# instead of the vbscript for opening a uft script. I already have the code to test to convert my vbcodes into c# but I need to add reference first the interop.quicktest.dll.
I have a UFT One version 15.01 and using Visual studio 2015.

I tried the manage NU get but the dll is not existing.
How do I find / download this dll for me to be able to use the Quick Test functionality?

The code I'm trying to work is just like on the https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/156466/How-to-Automate-Qtp-with-C-sharp

Please help on how I can add reference the dll to my application...

Best regards,
Mon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
It is actually not interop.quicktest.dll as the name of the dll to be added as reference to be able to use the code.. it is QTObjectModelLib.dll and QTObjectModel.dll which is located in the bin folder of the UFT installation.
In my case it is in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\Unified Functional Testing\bin

Then after adding it, the Quick Test exist also on the references.